# Compile WPF Xaml using Add-type of powershell without using PowerBoots

Tags: wpf, xaml, powershell, inline, add-type

I was tying to add WPF code-behind embedded in the XAML and compile using the powershell add-type.
There is PowerBoots but i don't want to use that. The code i am trying to Embed is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825527/gray-out-the-desktop-screen-except-a-selected-control-in-c) . I referred to [The PowershellGuy way](http://thepowershellguy.com/blogs/posh/archive/2008/05/19/wpf-from-powershell-the-making-of-the-wpf-wmi-explorer-part1.aspx) of implementation but still i need to use the code behind file.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName presentationframework
[xml]$xaml = @' 
<Window 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
Title="Window1"  Height="350" Width="525" AllowsTransparency="True"  
WindowStyle="None" 
WindowState="Maximized" Topmost="False"  IsHitTestVisible="False">
</Window> 
'@ 

$reader=(New-Object Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml) 
$Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader ) 
$Form.ShowDialog() | out-null
```

The code behind code from the link is

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
{ 
   base.OnRender(drawingContext); 
   var screenGeometry = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0, 0, ActualWidth,   ActualHeight)); 
   var excludeRectangle = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(200, 200, 150, 150)); 
   drawingContext.PushClip(CombinedGeometry.Combine(screenGeometry, excludeRectangle, GeometryCombineMode.Exclude, null)); 
   drawingContext.PushOpacity(.8);
   drawingContext.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Black, null, new Rect(0, 0, ActualWidth, ActualHeight));
   drawingContext.Pop(); drawingContext.Pop(); 
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have code-behind on XAML that's loaded via a XamlReader, which basically means that you can't do what you're trying to do (override the OnRender method of the Window in loose XAML) without creating a new type derived from the Window class ...

But that's overkill for what you're trying to do, I think:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName presentationframework
[xml]$xaml = @' 
<Window 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" 
Background="#AA000000" WindowState="Maximized" 
Height="{x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}"
Width="{x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}" 
Title="Window Title" Topmost="False"  IsHitTestVisible="False"></Window> 
'@ 

$reader=(New-Object Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml) 
$Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader ) 
$Form.ShowDialog() | out-null
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it helps but, here is an example, where some kind of PowerShell code is added behind the button "click" action.

```
#requires -version 2
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
[xml]$xaml = 
@"
<Window
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="408">
    <Grid>
      <Button x:Name="button1"
                Width="75"
                Height="23"
                Canvas.Left="118"
                Canvas.Top="10"
                Content="Click Here" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
"@

Clear-Host
$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$target=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)
$control=$target.FindName("button1")
$eventMethod=$control.add_click
$eventMethod.Invoke({$target.Title="Hello $((Get-Date).ToString('G'))"})
$target.ShowDialog() | out-null
```

Comment: It sounds good. I think embedding the C# code without XAML is preferable than the Xaml itself. THanks JPBlanc and JayKul!