# Darken the full screen when open popup

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-4.0

I have a window with a button. When you click the button popup appears. How can I darken the full screen when open popup?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I darken all screen area and glow my opened window in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520318/how-do-i-darken-all-screen-area-and-glow-my-opened-window-in-wpf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called [Adorner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx) what you are looking for. Link [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/d7e0dcdc-900d-4b8a-b13d-9a97f85fd167/) also might be of your interest.

Answer (score 0):

You should [write your own shader](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&newwindow=1&safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=wpf%20shader%20tutorial&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=d6df26cafee081d4&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44442042,d.bGE&biw=1920&bih=979) in order to darken, lighten, engraying, moting blurring and doing other cool graphics stuff.

Of course, if you don't want it to do in a right way, you could just create an `Rectangle` with `IsHitTestVisible = false` property and black color and some `0.5f` opacity all over your form, but...

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do this is to create a new UserControl like this:

```
<UserControl ...
<Grid Background="#AA000000"> <!-- control the overlay color here -->
        <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="10">
            <TextBlock Text="content"/>
        </Border>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Than just add it to the top grid of your window.